# PascalABC ошибка

Tags: pascalabc.net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пишу chat bot, PascalABC ошибка ошибка времени выполнения входная строка имела неверный формат помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вот она, пресловутая ошибка в 17 строке ;)

Переменная `name` имеет тип почему-то `Integer`, поэтому `readln`  ожидает ввод целого числа, а не `'Вася Пупкин'`.

Сделайте

```
var name: string;
```

и больше не приводите код скриншотами.